# what is the correct python bool expression for a custom object type (networkx graph type bool expression)?

Tags: python, networkx, boolean-expression

I need to check if an networkx (nx) graph is a digraph. for example,

```
In [70]: g = nx.DiGraph([(0,1), (2,0)])

In [71]: type(g)
Out[71]: networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph

In [72]: type(g) == 'networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph'
Out[72]: False
```

So the question is what do i put for right side of line`[72]` to make it work? Obviously I can do a different boolean, e.g., `'digraph.DiGraph' in str(type(g))` but that kinda goes around the more general issue of "how to check a custom type is what you need it to be with a boolean?"

Comment: You apparently have that type imported into your namespace as `nx.Digraph`.  Note that it is generally far better to do this as `isinstance(g, nx.Digraph)` than check for an exact type.

Comment: thanks, small edit (syntax), it should be: `isinstance(g, nx.DiGraph)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, fundamentally, the confusion you are encountering is because `type(g)` is a *type* object, i.e. a class object, but `'networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph'` is a *string*, and a `type` object won't equal a string. Instead, you could use:

```
type(g) == nx.DiGraph
```

Although typically you see:

```
type(g) is nx.DiGraph
```

But if you want to include *subclasses* you need `instanceof`:

```
instanceof(g, nx.DiGraph)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `isinstance` function:

```
isinstance(g, networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph)
```